# Database + Windows Authentication + Username/Password?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, windows-authentication

I have always thought that in order to connect to SQL server using windows authentication with explicitly specified credentials, you must LogonUser, Impersonate, then connect.

It seems to me that [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/spike/archive/2008/11/14/connectionstrings-mixing-usernames-and-windows-authentication-who-goes-first.aspx) suggests that it's possible to connect to SQL server without all this hassle, simply by specifying "uid=...;pwd=..." in connection string. I tested this method just to be sure it doesn't work, and - lo and behold - it didn't. If that blog post wasn't on msdn.com, I would have just dismissed it as noob talk, but it is.

Does anyone have an idea what am I missing?

**EDIT1:** Many respondents misunderstood what I was referring to. Here's a copy/paste of what I was talking about. It's *not* integrated SQL, nor it's an ASP.NET impersonation made by IIS:

```
string sql4 = String.Format(
   @"Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;uid=<uid>;pwd=<pid>", server);     
// Database + Windows Authentication + Username/Password
```

Comment: that's probably for sql server logins.

Comment: QUOTING: string sql4 = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;uid=<uid>;pwd=<pid>", server);     // Database + Windows Authentication + Username/Password

Comment: I believe when Integrated Security (Windows Authentication) and a username/password are both specified, then Integrated Security takes precedence.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are two distinct kinds of security with SQL Server. "Windows Authentication", and "SQL Server Authentication". When you see uid and pwd you're seeing the latter. The uid in this case is not a Windows principal - the OS knows nothing about it.

So the answer to your question is, **no**, you can't pass Windows user name and password in the connection string to log in to SQL Server.

Comment: Integrated Security=SSPI [indicates NT auth];uid=<uid>;pwd=<pid>[indicates sql auth] - both options in one line, why would they use it in this example?

Comment: It's not an example. It's an article. Go read the article and you'll understand.

Comment: actually Integrated Security=SSPI is a solution ...

Answer (score 5):

It depends - if you connect from a command-line or Winforms app DIRECTLY to your SQL Server, you EITHER specify "Integrated Security=SSPI;" and then use your Windows credentials as logon credentials, OR you specify "user id=....;pwd=....." - but that's then a SQL logon - NOT your Windows logon.

You mention "impersonate and then connect" - that seems to indicate ASP.NET - that's a totally different story again. If you impersonate, then you're basically using your Windows credentials, e.g. the web server will "impersonate" you and log on as you (using your Windows credentials). In that case, again, no "uid=....;pwd=....." needs to be specified (if it is, it will be ignored).

As that link you mentioned clearly shows - if you can connect directly, and you specify "Integrated Security=SSPI;", then this takes precedence over any uid=...;pwd=.... which you might also specified and logs you in using your Windows credentials; those extra uid=...;pwd=.... pieces are ignored.

Marc

Answer (score 2):

The article and point in question relates to SQL security, not integrated security. You can pass the credentials for a SQL user and log in in this manner if SQL authentication (mixed mode) is enabled. If the SQL server is set up to use integrated security only then this will not work. It will also not work to allow logging in using Windows logon credentials.

Answer (score 1):

In our shop, we routinely use connection strings like you describe.  No problemo.  But your sql server database must be set up to use sql security, not windows authentication.

A sample connection string (from web.config) in our app looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConfigurationData" connectionString="server=DevServer;
database=travel_expense_management_dv;uid=userid;pwd=password!;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

On the other hand, the DBA guru for our shop set me up a personal database on the main server that had integrated security with my Windows logon.  I didn't need uid and pwd because it took my authentication info from context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you say, the article mentions this:

```
string sql4 = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;uid=<uid>;pwd=<pid>", server);     // Database + Windows Authentication + Username/Password
```

But if you carefully read few lines later, it says this:

> string sql4 -> Logs in with Windows login, ie. takes precedence over the username/password.

:)

Answer (score 1):

This is very old but maybe someone has the same issue.

You **can** connect using **WindowsAuthentication** and **specifying user id and password on your connection string**, but not on every device. You can achieve this for example **on WinCE** devices (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275613(v=sql.80).aspx).

I don't know if you can do the same thing on other OS just with the connection string (without doing the impersonation thing).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just a contribution also for some who was still encountering problem like this.  Based on my experience if you don't specify any user/password in you connectivity it will automatically connect to db using windows authentication.  Meaning it will get the userid and it's credential of the user who logged on to the machine.  The system will allow you to connect to database if it identifies that your userid exist/created in the database.  But once you specify your userid and password in your connectivity it bypass the windows authentication and use sql server authentication instead.