# Add user id and password to edmx

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, web-config, edmx

I have added edmx file using my windows credentials. Latter I wanted to change the connection string to a specific user ID and password. I have updated the web.Config and updated the emdx file. When I look at SQL profiler its still using windows credentials rather than connect with the userid and password. 
Am I missing something.

Comment: here is my connection string <add name="ConnString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Testing.csdl|res://*/Models.Testing.ssdl|res://*/Models.Testing.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;User ID=userid;Password=password;integrated security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Comment: Remove integrated security=SSPI

Answer (score 0):

replace "integrated security=SSPI" with "persist security info=True"

Comment: Didn't work. I forgot to menthion this, the userid that I am using is a domain account so it has domain\username and its not working.

Comment: Alright then... if you're unable to use a SQL Server account, you may be in for some additional work.  I have not used a domain user personally.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312853/connection-string-using-a-domain-user

Comment: Thanks Mark for the pointers, I did encounter this stackoverflow regarding domain account. But wanted to make sure that it worked both ways for server and locally run. So I had implement Impersonate, set the app pool to domain account and gave the permissions to IIS_USRS  and it worked on server. Locally when running from Visual studio I am still having login failed for the domain account.

Comment: For running locally, I would set up a site in IIS and use that rather than the Visual Studio Development Server (from the Web tab in the project properties).  You can then set up your app pool in a similar fashion to the solution you found on the server.  Good luck.  Sounds like you're almost there.