# R - Manual RODBC Windows Authentication

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

When using RODBC to connect to Microsoft SQL Server I know I can do the following:

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="driver={SQL Server};server=servername;database=dbname;trusted_connection=yes;")
```

However, that limits me to using the windows authentication for my current windows username.  Our processes often require using different log in credentials for different processes.  If I need to use a different log in credential using windows authentication is there a way to do that manually?  For example, the following fails for me.

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="driver={SQL Server};server=servername;database=dbname;uid=domain\\username;pwd=passwd;")
```

I thought I could use the format `domain\\username` but it never works and I just keep getting an error like this:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "driver={SQL Server};server=servername;database=dbname;uid=domain\username;pwd=passwd") :
>     [RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code 18456, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\username'

My concern is that this is impossible given the answer I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312853/connection-string-using-a-domain-user).

This is rather frustrating because I can use an arbitrary user if I use [RSQLServer](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer).

```
con <- dbConnect(RSQLServer::SQLServer(), "servername", database = "dbname",
                    properties = list(user = "username", password = "passwd",
                                      useNTLMv2=TRUE, domain = "domain")
                    )
```

I would prefer to use `RODBC` in this situation though because a lot of previously written code depends upon the `RODBC` specific functions (e.g. `sqlQuery`) instead of the `DBI` functions.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli thanks for the comment but that is doesn't work because with `trusted_connection` it ignores `uid` and `pwd` and uses the current windows user as the login.  I need to use a different login.

Comment: i think i get your point. let me try other alternatives.

Comment: You could try using FreeTDS as an ODBC driver instead of using Microsoft's ODBC drivers. If I recall correctly, FreeTDS still supports an older authentication protocol that permits the sort of login you describe.

Comment: if you have admin rights, you can set up ODBC system data source connections. then you can connect using `odbcConnect(servername)`

Comment: Yes, if you have admin rights on the machine where R runs, you can create a User or System DNS (look for ODBC Data Sources in windows menu) storing the connection informations and then odbcConnect to that source.

Comment: Otherwise the only way is running R with the correct user... maybe using runas command or something similar...

Comment: Can you try on your own machine to add Windows Credentials towards this specific database user? Cf. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/  If this works, I am quite sure IT can find a way to deploy credentials for a list of users